# Postfix: prevent users from changing the real e-mail address

Tags: postfix, smtp

My postfix e-mail server is finally working well.

Now, I need to prevent users from forging their e-mail addresses in the client programs in the "from" field in the header, because a user can send email as other user with that, and a unexperienced user can think that is real.

If a user is experienced, he can inspect the email headers and know what is happening, but is there a way to block this behaviour?

Comment: So, how gmail does that? I tried to change my email name using gmail, and i am blocked immediately! so...

Comment: @Shadur SMTP doesn't, but this protection can be made on top of SMTP. The local sender (postfix) must check the user names (LHS of the From address) exactly as requested in this question, and must sign the headers in such a way that the recipient machine can verify which machine sent the email (search "DKIM").

Comment: Pretty much. Unfortunately I had a train to catch, hence lack of a longer response.

Comment: Tarleb. Thank you. Now this security issue gone away, you answer are great!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at the `smtpd_sender_restrictions` and `smtpd_sender_login_maps` settings.  The former can prevent malformed `from` addresses, while the latter can force the sender address to match the login name.

```
# Prevent malformed senders
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
    reject_non_fqdn_sender       # Ensure correct mail addresses
    reject_unknown_sender_domain # Ensure sender address is from an existing domain
    reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch # Check if the user is 
                                 # allowed to use this sender address

# Maps used to stop sender address forgeries.
smtpd_sender_login_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/login_maps.pcre
```

The contents of `login_maps.pcre` could be

```
# Use this regex if your users are local users, i.e. if the login name
# is just the username, not a full mail address.
# Note that literal dots have to be backslash escaped (`\.`) to avoid
# interpretation of these dots as regex wildcard.
/^([^@+]*)(\+[^@]*)?@example\.com$/ ${1}

# If one doesn't care about subaddresses, this could be simplified to
/^(.*)@example\.com/ ${1}

# This is appropriate if you have virtual users who login with their
# full mail address as their username.  Local addresses won't work, though
/^(.*)$/    ${1}
```

The above config assumes that postfix was compiled with support for PCRE.  On Ubuntu/Debian, this requires the `postfix-pcre` package to be installed.

Note that this will only work if nobody but authenticated users can send mail.  If you allow mail from unauthenticated users, the above method won't help and will fail. Make sure to read Rui F Ribeiro's answer if that's the case.

Comment: I suggest adding `reject_unknown_sender_domain` after `reject_non_fqdn_sender`; the login_maps are quite interesting, assuming all users have to login to send email; wont it create problems with non-authenticated emails, if any? ;  You also need postfix compiled with pcre.

Comment: You are correct with both point, I'll edit the answer. Thanks!

Comment: btw, I was the one of the guys giving you +1

Comment: why would anyone compile postfix without pcre?  sure, it's easy to do, but it's about as real-world-useful as building a car without brakes.

Comment: Thanks @RuiFRibeiro :) This friendly, solution oriented atmosphere here at SE is what I love the most.

Comment: @cas In Debian there is the postfix package, and then there is postfix-pcre

Comment: yeah, i know. i used to maintain the postfix-tls package when there was still such a thing as the non-us archive.   debian likes to not take choices away from people with pre-compiled packages, even if the choices don't make much sense.  in practice, pretty much everyone installs postfix-pcre along with postfix.

Comment: @cas I just confirmed, the normal and default postfix package does not support pcre.

Comment: @tarleb, I would suggest adding to the post that if in Debian or Ubuntu, you need to install the postfix-pcre package

Comment: that's because they split out the pcre functionality into a separate module package so that users could choose.  `postfix-pcre` contains little more than `/usr/lib/postfix/postfix-pcre.so.1.0.1`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro agreed. done.

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini have  you seen logs, or tried to do some debugging with postfix?

Comment: Yes, beautiful! Is working now. Thank you everybody! With this answer we can see how safe postfix can be!

Comment: Note that `smtpd_sender_login_maps` applies to envelope addresses (AKA "MAIL FROM") only. Users could still forge the "From:" header (AKA "RFC5322.From").

Answer (score 2):

While SMTP forging cannot be prevented, and the underlying protocol was not designed with security in mind,  you can minimise in postfix the effects of email forging by your internal users.

You can configure your postfix and clients to be mandatory to authenticate to send email via port 587 with authentication.

That does not however prevent them from sending email, however, it makes the life of spam malware more difficult (but not impossible).

As for gmail, they have lots of the customisations to the code, or even their own proprietary email server. Back when I managed an ISP, I collected and wrote extensions to QMail that did not allow it to forward emails that were not from our domain, and also only accepting existing authenticated users in the FROM field (e.g. double checking the FROM with the user doing the authentication)

To relay email only for authenticated users in postfix, make sure you have in the file `/etc/postfix/main.cf` at the beginning of the `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` directive the following two options:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
```

For more details, please check the official documentation at [Postfix SMTP relay and access control](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html)

Comment: Rui, thank you for the information i think its is already mandatory, how can i check this in the configuration file?

Comment: @LucianoAndressMartini talking about patches, have a look at the VDA patches for postfix. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

When sending mails via SMTP, the sender mail address appears at two different positions: in the SMTP-`MAIL FROM` request, and in the `From` mail header field. Some MUAs only show the value of the `From` mail header field.

## Prevent forged envelope `MAIL FROM` addresses

For preventing  users authenticated via SMTP from forging sender addresses, the option `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` can be used. Then, `smtpd_sender_login_maps` should be adapted as well:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
  ...
  reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch,
  ...
smtpd_sender_login_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/maps/smtpd_sender_login_map.pcre
```

The contents of `/etc/postfix/maps/smtpd_sender_login_map.pcre` should then be according to [tarleb’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/294308/147881):

> - Use this regex if your users are local users, i.e. if the login name
>     is just the username, not a full mail address.  Note that literal dots
>     have to be backslash escaped (`\.`) to avoid interpretation of these dots
>     as regex wildcard:
>
>   `/^([^@+]*)(\+[^@]*)?@example\.com$/    ${1}`
> - If one doesn't care about subaddresses, this could be simplified to:
>
>   `/^(.*)@example\.com/ ${1}`
> - This is appropriate if you have virtual users who login with their
>     full mail address as their username.  Local addresses won't work, though:
>
>   `/^(.*)$/   ${1}`
>
> The above config assumes that postfix was compiled with support for PCRE.  On Ubuntu/Debian, this requires the `postfix-pcre` package to be installed.

The `sendmail` command will still allow local users to choose an arbitrary from address when sending, which is problematic with hacked user accounts. The easiest solution to this problem is probably to restrict the usage of the sendmail command in Postfix’ `main.cf`, e.g.:

```
authorized_submit_users = root
```

## Prevent forged `From` mail header addresses

Postfix does not seem to provide some easy solution to this by itself. However, it can be accomplished with a [milter](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html).

For [Rspamd](https://rspamd.com/doc/integration.html), you can create/extend the configuration file `/etc/rspamd.local.lua` by the following code:

```lua
local logger = require 'rspamd_logger'

rspamd_config:register_symbol({
  name = 'FROM_HEADER_MISMATCH',
  callback = function(task)
    local user = task:get_user()
    if not user then
      return 0
    end
    for index, smtp_sender in pairs(task:get_from(1)) do
      if smtp_sender.addr ~= user then
        logger.infox('invalid SMTP sender: %1', smtp_sender.addr)
        return 1
      end
    end
    for index, mime_sender in pairs(task:get_from(2)) do
      if mime_sender.addr ~= user then
        logger.infox('invalid MIME sender: %1', mime_sender.addr)
        return 1
      end
    end
    return 0
  end,
  score = 16,
  description = 'sender address in at least one mail header ' ..
    'differs from the sender address in the envelope'
})
```

This will mark mail with multiple from addresses as spam and cause rejection of the message by Postfix. It prevents forged `From` headers only if the envelope headers cannot be forged (see first part of the answer).

Alternatively, the milter [vrfydmn](https://github.com/croessner/vrfydmn) is also able to replace the address in the `From` mail header by the SMTP `MAIL FROM` address.