# Postfix spam (hack)

Tags: security, postfix

My `mailq` is getting filled with reports about email been sent (to for example freshsamuel2009@yahoo.com) by non existing local user (for example jeanne_cox@localdomains.tld)

`mailq` example:

```
8F979561A3     1440 Thu Aug 25 13:54:32  jeanne_cox@localdomains.tld
(delivery temporarily suspended: connect to 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024: Connection refused)
                                         freshsamuel2009@yahoo.com
```

How can I stop it?

my `main.cf` is:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/smtpd.key
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = faster2.jbmd.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination =  localhost, localhost.localdomain
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
html_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/html
virtual_alias_domains = 
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/virtual-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
inet_protocols = all
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, check_recipient_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_recipient.cf
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
transport_maps = hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/transport-mailman, proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_transports.cf
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relaydomains.cf
relay_recipient_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_relayrecipientmaps.cf
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_canonical_maps $recipient_canonical_maps $relocated_maps $transport_maps $mynetworks
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unlisted_sender,  reject_unknown_sender_domain,check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_originating.re, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, check_sender_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender.cf, check_sender_access regexp:/etc/postfix/tag_as_foreign.re 
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unknown_client_hostname, check_client_access mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_client.cf reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,  reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org
smtpd_client_message_rate_limit = 100
maildrop_destination_concurrency_limit = 1
maildrop_destination_recipient_limit = 1
virtual_transport = dovecot
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks
nested_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/nested_header_checks
body_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
owner_request_special = no
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3
smtpd_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
smtp_tls_protocols = !SSLv2,!SSLv3
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
receive_override_options = no_address_mappings
message_size_limit = 0
default_process_limit = 150
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
```

Answer (score 3):

In the best of the scenarios, one or more of your users is compromised e.g. bad actors guessed/phished the password.

Since you allow sending email from authenticated users, they are most probably faking the From field to avoid detection.

Editing the full body of a couple of relevant messages will give you a hint of which user(s) you have compromised.

As a starting point I would advise restricting the From field to known users, have a look at this thread. [Postfix: prevent users from changing the real e-mail address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294300/postfix-prevent-users-from-changing-the-real-e-mail-address)

As the middle scenario, you can have an exploit of some page/cgi in a web server *if the postfix server is running Apache*.

As the worst scenario, you can have a compromised box.

Have a look at postfix and Apache access logs (if you have Apache), it will give you a more reasonable idea of what it is happening.

EDIT: After @P.Masher posted an example of the deferred message:

The relevant line to pay attention is:

```
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 5015:alias.php(1944) : eval()'d code
```

What it says it that you have a script name `alias.php`, possibly planted in a less secure directory accessible to your web server (Apache?), that is the culprit for sending the emails.

The script will have to be deleted, and the directory *and* any other possible way in (old wordpress, SQL injection, old webmail interface) the spammers have used to plant this script will have to be closed.

A temporary solution may be stopping the web server altogether.

I would also collect web server logs of the access to `alias.php` and would send them to the local CERT. (if you have one that you usually work with )

As for more security considerations, the fact they are executing code through an eval() means they basically have access to any file the user that is running the vhost/Apache has access. i.e. it is the same as having a *remote* shell account in the server.

If the server is old/has no updates, they might as well have leveraged privileges to root level in the worst scenario; in the best scenario, they only have access equivalent to the web server non-privileged user, but may have already tried to leverage passwords from HTML/PHP files, and might as well have collected the hashed passwords of your postfix users.

I would advise to:

1) Reinstall the server if it is too old or has no security updates;
2) Change DB/root passwords;
3) Advise the postfix users to change their passwords just in case.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44518/discussion-on-answer-by-rui-f-ribeiro-postfix-spam-hack).